# Scala Compiler (2.11.7) anomaly with Play JSON Writes

Tags: json, scala, playframework, scala-2.11

So I have the following code:

Base:

```
import play.api.libs.json.{JsNull, Json, JsValue, Writes}
case class Cost(cost: Option[Double])
```

This compiles:

```
case object Cost {
  def writes = new Writes[Cost] {
    override def writes(r: Cost): JsValue = {
      val cost = r.cost.map(Json.toJson(_)).getOrElse(JsNull)
      Json.obj(
        "cost" -> cost
      )
    }
  }
}
```

But this doesn't compile

```
case object Cost {
  def writes = new Writes[Cost] {
    override def writes(r: Cost): JsValue = {
      Json.obj(
        "cost" -> r.cost.map(Json.toJson(_)).getOrElse(JsNull)
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Compiler error is the following:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Object
[error]  required: play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper
[error]         "cost" -> r.cost.map(Json.toJson(_)).getOrElse(JsNull)
```

In the latter if I use .asInstanceOf[JsValue] it works, but with IntelliJ grays it out saying it's unnecessary as it can't be anything else that JsValue anyway. What might be the reason that Scala compiler (2.11.7) doesn't detect the Class properly?

Comment: Compiling directly with SBT ?

Comment: Yes compiling from SBT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure the issue comes from `.getOrElse(JsNull)`

I have successfully compiled this code:

```
import play.api.libs.json.{JsNull, Json, JsValue, Writes}

case class Cost(cost: Option[Double])

case object Cost {
  def writes = new Writes[Cost] {
    override def writes(r: Cost): JsValue = {
      Json.obj(
        "cost" -> r.cost.map(Json.toJson(_))
      )
    }
  }
}
```

and parsed the output:

```
scala> Cost(Some(5))
res2: Cost = Cost(Some(5.0))

scala> Json.toJson(res2)(Cost.writes)
res5: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"cost":5}
```

---

Looking for the source of the issue you can check couple of additional solutions, assuming the writes function:

```
val cost = r.cost.map(t => Json.toJson(t))
Json.obj(
  "cost" -> cost
)
```

if you want to resolve the `Option` of `cost` value with `getOrElse` you can either cast (as you have tried) or provide the type:

```
cost.getOrElse[JsValue](JsNull)
cost.getOrElse(JsNull).asInstanceOf[JsValue]
```

and without the type specification `sbt` always gives an error saying:

```
[error] (...) type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Object
[error]  required: play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper
```

which must come from some SBT's compiler bug.

Comment: That seems to work like I wish as well. Previously I was using the default def writes = Json.writes[Cost] which doesn't include any None-fields in the JSON as null, which is something the API needed. It doesn't still explain the compiler type error in the original post, as JsNull is JsValue as well as is the return value of Json.toJson.